# Javascript - XMLHttp Update (parameters)

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having a little trouble with this, I've always got myself confused over the way javascript parameters in functions work.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
function update(port, account) {
    $.get( "include/serverlist.php", { f: port + "-" + account +"-41" }).done(function( data ) {
        $('#autoUpdate' + port).html(data);
        setTimeout(update, 1000);
    });
}
</script>
```

and I'm calling it from a PHP while loop (for multiple servers)

```
echo '<script>update("'.$port.'","'.$account.'");</script>';
```

when the page is loaded, this is the output of the above code:

```
<script>update("28500","NOBODY");</script>
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?
Thank you!

Edit, the div is on the page with the correct ID etc,

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="table-responsive" id="autoUpdate28500">
    <!-- Auto Updating -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The trouble I'm having with this is that nothing is being displayed inside the "autoupdate" element on the page, if I load (include/serverlist.php) with the correct GET information, it displays everything fine, there is error reporting on that page if any GET info is missing. However, on the main page (index.php) where this script is, it isn't updating anything in the "autoUpdate" div

I think it could be the way I've called the javascript variables in the statements, (port, account) and (port +) but I'm unsure.

Comment: What is actually going wrong here?

Comment: What part is it that you don't understand? The scenario you set up seems logical enough to me, and I can't even see what anyone would be confused about. Can you clarify so we can help you better?

Comment: Nothing is being displayed when update() is being called with the parameters, the updating page (include/serverlist.php) is loading fine if I open it directly with the correct GET information, there is error reporting in the code on that page to tell me whether any of the get data is missing. However, on the main page (index.php) where this script is, it isn't updating anything in the "autoUpdate" div

Comment: Edit your question and include this information. That's pretty relevant if we are to see what is even going on.

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? If you open F12 developer tools, what do you see under "network"? Does the request succeed? Did you try specifying an absolute path instead of a relative path?

Comment: The paths are correct, this was working absolutely fine when I didn't have parameters in the function

Comment: Solved this. The while loop was repeating itself. Thanks for all of your help

Comment: What while loop are you talking about?